# Checking if the value exists in database

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration2.php

in this code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email"/><br>
    <label>Heslo</label><input type="password" name="password"/><br>
    <label>Heslo znovu</label><input type="password" name="passwordagain"/><br>
    <label>Nickname</label><input type="text" name="nickname"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['nickname'])){
    $nickname= $_POST['nickname'];

    $sql4 = "SELECT nickname FROM registration WHERE nickname = :nickname";
    $sql4->execute(array(":nickname"=>$nickname));
    if($sql4->rowCount() > 0){
        echo "toto jméno již existuje";
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your database connection? and execute work with database connection link variable bay passing query into it as an argument? Also you mix  bind and execute.

Comment: `$sql4` is a string, not an object. You define it right there in your code snippet.

Comment: So what do i have to do when sql4 is a string

Comment: @StarScrime First you need to [establish a database connection.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Nah i have good database connection.. i just didnt post it there .. the problem is in this code that i have sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to call a method on a string, which isn't an object, hence your error.

First you need to prepare your SQL query, then execute it.

I've assumed your PDO object to be called `$dbh`, replace it with your own:

```
if(isset($_POST['nickname'])){
    $nickname= $_POST['nickname'];

    $sql4 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT nickname FROM registration WHERE nickname = :nickname");
    $sql4->execute(array(":nickname"=>$nickname));
    if($sql4->rowCount() > 0){
        echo "toto jméno již existuje";
    }

}
```